# Failed to fetch Error 404 Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: upgrade, updates

I have been searching for this topic and try many answers but still no positive results

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/petrakis/wdt-main/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/petrakis/wdt-main/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/petrakis/wdt-main/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/screenlets/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/screenlets/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/screenlets/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Each time I try to update I get this error.
I try to use the script that they recommend in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa) and still the same error.

Any idea?